# Projectivization of the normal bundle of $\mathbb P^4$ in the 10-spinor variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians, cotangent-bundles

Let $X=S_{10} \subset \mathbb P^{15}$ be the 10-dimensional spinor variety in its minimal embedding. Consider a $\mathbb P^4 \subset S_{10}$, hence we can define the normal bundle $N=N_{\mathbb P^4|S_{10}}=\wedge^2 T_{\mathbb P^4}$. Moreover, we can define the $\mathbb P^5$-bundle (using the Grothendieck notation)
$$
\pi:X=\mathbb P(N^\vee)=\mathbb P(\wedge^2(\Omega_{\mathbb P^4}(1))) \to \mathbb P^4.
$$
$X$ is a smooth projective variety with a line bundle $\mathcal O(1)$ such that $\pi_* \mathcal O(1)=\wedge^2(\Omega_{\mathbb P^4}(1))$. I want to understand who is $H^0(X, \mathcal O(1))$

Comment: I don't understand the question: by definition, $H^0(X,\mathscr{O}_X(1))$ is $H^0(\mathbb{P}^4, \wedge^2(\Omega_{\mathbb P^4}(1)))$. Are you asking how to describe this space? That should be easy (use the Euler exact sequence).

Comment: That's the problem! I know that $X$ contains the incidence variety $I=\{(p, \mathbb P^2): p \in \mathbb P^2 \subset \mathbb P^4\}$, which is contained in $\mathbb P( \mathbb C^5 \otimes \wedge^2 \mathbb C^5)=\mathbb P^{49}$. So I expect that $h^0(X, \mathcal O(1)) \ge 50$, but using the Bott formula in the Okonek book, this does not happens...

Comment: In fact $H^0(\mathbb{P}^4,\wedge^2(\Omega_{\mathbb P^4}(1)))=0$. I don't understand at all your argument for $h^0\geq 50$.